# Не работает код и выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, pyowm

Я написал код:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('Мой API ключ', Language = "ru")
place = input("В каком городе/стране?: ")
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)

w = observation.get_weather()
print(w)
```

Но он не работает, пишет следующую ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации в pyowm.OWM нужно передавать словарь. Вот пример с Githab:

```
config_dict = config.get_default_config_for_subscription_type('professional')
owm = OWM('your paid OWM API key', config_dict)
```

То есть `config_dict = {'language': 'ru'}`

Comment: `config.get_default_config_for_subscription_type` что за жуть? :D Для чего так сложно? :)

Comment: Да и не нужно ли будет распаковать словарь по аргументам? Проще просто `owm = pyowm.OWM('Мой API ключ', language="ru")`

Comment: Не знаю для чего так сложно, но это с официального Git pyowm пример. А словарь распаковывать не нужно. Там и ожидается словарь и ничего кроме словаря

Comment: Спасибо, я был неправ :) У `OWM` в конструкторе только два параметра `api_key` и `config`, причем второй должен быть словарем (https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/e7ccb5ec3f86bee0cbb9981070a62988a83a5b3c/pyowm/owm.py#L27). Кст, мб тогда возможно лучше использовать этот пример: https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3/code-recipes.html#language-setting т.e. получить `config_dict = get_default_config()` и в нем поменять `language`

Comment: да, config_dict = get_default_config() и config_dict['language'] = 'ru' должно сработать